# Streaming videos on Web and Mobile applications

Tags: video-streaming, streaming, webrtc, rtsp, kurento

I'm currently investigating a way to build the following scenario - Mobile application written with C++(NDK for Android) + Web application written in Python(Django and Angular/React/Expo) and a web server that will allow both of the clients, initiate a video streaming session between them.

The project is for self learn and I'm trying to find the best solution in the subject of what technologies i should get involved with.

I read about :

1. SIP - The alerting protocol to start VoIP calls and video sessions, but i read people prefer to use him only as voice calls and not Video ones.
2. RTSP - Responsible to start streaming sessions between 2 endpoints.
3. WebRTC - framework that provides a way to stream video from web applications. Which gives us the SIP + RTP abilities without using any additional software/hardware.

As far as for now, I'm trying to make my mind what platform/protocols should i use or how to even use them..

- For what i understand about streaming media/voice calls from a web application(browser), must I use the WebRTC? or we have today other solution for that problem?
- Considering mobile applications(Android/Windows Phone/iOS) i can theoretically use SIP+RTP for that matter(correct me if i'm mistaken) and as well use RTSP. Are there any more optional older/new possibilities for that matter?

Thanks heads up for every answers if I'm not answering right away :)

Comment: What is it you are trying to build? Is that a streaming service where one device streams media to another (or to many others); or is it a conversation type of service where a person on one device needs to speak to another person (or a group of people talking together in a "meeting")?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make video calls, you can do it using vanilla WebRTC (see [WebRTC Samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/)). There are libraries (Jssip, Sip.js, etc) that implement SIP on top of WebRTC, taking advantage of the signalling standard and opening the possibility to use SIP servers to make easier communications (e.g. asterisk)

If you do really need RTSP, you should realize that RTSP is not supported directly with WebRTC. You could use (there are several approaches to your problem), something like [janus-gateway](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/) .

Other very attracting possibility is using **asterisk** with **chan_rtsp**. You could make a web app using a SIP library on top of WebRTC and make invite calls to the camera you wish to. Unfortunately, this module does not work without patches in latest versions of the PBX software.